# Using aotimport on server startup

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, aot

I'm trying to set up one of my AX environments to have an XPO imported whenever the server process is started up. Because the environment is updated from production on a regular basis, and the code needs to be unique to this (non-production) environment, it seems the best option would be to use the AOTImport command on startup. However, I'm having trouble identifying the exact syntax/setup to get this to work.

Looking through the system code, it seems the syntax should be `aotimport_[path to file]`. Is this correct? The server does not seem to complain about this command, but the file in question does not get imported. I have also tried variations on this command, but have not seen it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you're trying to execute a command on `SysStartupCmd` classes. If so, this methods are fired when AX **client** starts, not the AOS. It's docummented on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569641(v=ax.50).aspx

If you want to automate this import it can be done scheduling an execution of the AX client (ax32.exe) on your build workflow that run the import (it's recommended to run a full compilation after importing). This is discussed on other questions here on SO.

Comment: my primary sources were [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569637(v=ax.50).aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569617(v=ax.50).aspx) on MSDN, which don't explicitly state which commands are server vs client. The server `-startupCmd` flag implies I should be able to execute a `SysStartupCmd` command on server startup. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: If you want to see the available commands, you can have a look in the SysStartupCmd::Construct method and have a look at the switch statement there.

Comment: I did that as well. `aotimport` is such a command, and that's how I was able to get the syntax in my original post.